# Namespaces in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, namespaces

Is there such a thing as JSON namespaces, just like XML namespaces? Has anyone created a spec or libraries for this? Is this a good or a terrible idea?

I want to make a data spec that can be represented in XML as well as JSON. However I also need the namespace concept, that the data can be extended by annotations in different vocabularies.

To be more specific, this is about representing events. My schema will describe the event in basic terms (time and location), though if you think about it, events can be annotated with different information e.g. attendees or image URLs which I don't want to specify in my schema.

Comment: You probably mean *JavaScript* namespaces; JSON is just a notation (JavaScript Object Notation).

Comment: Namespaces do not exist in JSON in it's current specification

Comment: If you provide a use case, maybe someone will think of a solution that could help.

Comment: @Marcel no I do mean JSON, since it's a data format similar to XML.

Comment: See also Mark Nottingham's [Thinking about Namespaces in JSON](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2011/10/12/thinking_about_namespaces_in_json) for added perspective and suggestions.

Comment: **See also:** http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/201506/msg00024.html

Answer (score 6):

[JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/) might help :

> "JSON-LD (JavaScript Object Notation for Linking Data) is a lightweight Linked Data format that gives your data context."

Answer (score 2):

JSON Schema might be the right thing for this:

http://json-schema.org/

Althought I don't know how well it's implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old thread, but there are JSON prefixes, which are almost like namespaces. If you are using Java server-side with [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/User%27s+Guide), you can easily meet them.