# Make XML a string to put in JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, xml

For example I want this sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="someLink"
    xmlns:ns2="someLink"
    xmlns:vh="someLink"
    xmlns:wsa="someLink"
    xmlns:xsi="someLink">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsa:MessageID>someID</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo />
        <wsa:To>someLink</wsa:To>
        ...
```

to be included here:

```
{
    "xmlData": "xmlAboveToString", 
    "additionalData": "data1", 
    "additionalData2": "data2"
}
```

I need this because the XML is from a third-party API and the API I'm creating needs to be JSON.

Comment: *"to be included"* or *converted into*? the easiest way would be to do it manually. parse that xml through soap service contract into a POCO then pass it to json serializer.

Comment: hi @BagusTesa could you provide an example or a link to this method?

Comment: is it [.net framework (3.5, 4.5, 4.8)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12710348/4648586) or [.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x)? also, is the producer of the soap service written in .net? do you have access to the web service? do you have the wsdl? the answer may change which approach we can use.

Comment: afaik mapping xml to json in general is [not well defined](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+soap+to+json), some strip away the namespacing while others [preserves it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777513/namespaces-in-json). the best way is to know what those field represent and how they will be consumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just encode the XML string encoded with Base64, then use a string property in the payload to keep it.
This will work, but the data must be very small, perhaps up to size of several kB only. Be careful on using the correct XML encoding, it will be perfectly binary preserved when using the Base64 string.

Comment: Yes, attach as a base64 string, but it gets complicated really fast. Without knowing the exact use case it difficult. Why does the API have to be JSON?

Comment: @plykkegaard it has to be JSON because I need to add additionalData from my end as well. I could use all xml, but the additional data won't be added properly.

Comment: Then embed the XML document as a base64 encoded string

Comment: BTW, using Base64 is just to avoid a more complex string-escaping technique though. It 'resolves' all special characters out of the string, such as quotes or new-lines, etc.. That's quite usual way to do that in fact.